# How do I dynamically update displayed elements in D3

Tags: d3.js

I have a function that loads an initial array of points onto a map using D3:

```
  var fires = []; //huge array of objects 

  function update(selection) {

    feature = g.selectAll("path")
     .data(selection);

    feature.attr("class", "update");

    feature.enter().append("path")
     .attr("class", "enter")
     .style("fill", function(d) {return colorScale(d.area)});

    feature.exit().remove(); 
  }
```

I call it initially with a large array:

```
update(fires);
```

I also have a histogram that allows me to narrow down the selection based on years. Using a D3 brush, on 'brushend' I call a function called brushed:

```
function brushed() {
    if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // only transition after input
    var extent0 = brush.extent();
    startYear = Math.floor(extent0[0]);
    endYear = Math.floor(extent0[1]);

    var selectedFires = fires.filter(function(fire) {
        if(fire.year >= startYear && fire.year <= endYear) return fire;
    });

    console.log(selectedFires.length); //does reflect the proper amount of elements

    update(selectedFires);
}
```

When I narrow the selection, the points on the map disappear as expected. When I widen it, the points/elements do not return. The array is getting the correct elements in it, they're just not being appended to the SVG.

I'm missing something fundamental as the examples I've seen: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 appear to append elements just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code (which really helps), and focusing on your selection piece alone, try this:

```
function update(selection) {
    // binding the data
    feature = g.selectAll(".path")
        .data(selection);

    // exit selection
    feature
      .exit()
      .remove();

    // enter selection
    feature
      .enter()
      .append("path")
        .attr("class","path");

    // update selection
    feature
        .style("fill", function(d) {return colorScale(d.area)});

    // update selection
    feature
        .style("fill", function(d) {return colorScale(d.area)})
        .attr("d",path); // this was the missing piece!
}
```

NOTE: you also want to comment out where you hardcoded the extent of the brush:

```
//brush
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(areaYearScale)
    //.extent([1984, 2013]) // comment this out
    .on("brushend", brushed);
```

Comment: I suppose you're right, there is no valid reason why I shouldn't keep this one out of view. (It's a federal project and they're very weird about ANY code written for them being publicly available) but this is more of an experiment. This can be seen at https://github.com/nobleach/mtbs-storymaps/blob/master/app/js/main.js The code is a complete mess at the moment, but perhaps it'll give you better insight.

Comment: @JimWharton I downloaded the code and investigated the problem. The paths were being redrawn without the `d` attribute, which is fundamental since these are the drawing commands. I updated the code with the one line that will help you out.

Comment: @JimWharton In summary, substitute your current `update` function for the one in the response above and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! That would have eluded me for hours upon hours! Thank you so much.

Comment: YMW. The product you have built so far looks nice.